# Heat Map in TChart

Tags: delphi, heatmap, teechart, delphi-xe4

Hello I'm trying to get a graphic where I have 3 value points. One value for X axis, other for Y axis and the third one, is a color dependant value point. I found that it could be a "heat map". My idea is to implement it in Delphi XE4 with TChart Pro VCL. Has anyone had done it with that tools?. I think I can use a TColorGrid series but not sure about. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I have only used the TChartSeries, but sounds liek the one for your use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to take a look at the Features Demo program shipped with the installation (also downloadable in a standalone zip under the **TeeChart compiled demo** section [here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl)).

Concretely, I'd suggest you to look at the ColorGrid examples under "All features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Extended\Color Grid"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yeray. I will.